# How do I make an observable depend on another observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem understanding the order of events when building 2 observables that depend on the same underlying source. I hope you can not only help me with a working solution, but also explain why I get the outcome below. My goal is that `observable2` never emits before `observable1`.

**Code**

```js
const filters$ = new Subject();

const observable1 = filters$.pipe(
  map(() => 'obersvable1')
);

const observable2 = observable1.pipe(
  map(() => 'observable2')
)

observable2.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
observable1.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

**Expected outcome**

```
observable1
observable2
```

**Actual outcome**

```
observable2
observable1
```

The problem is that when the `filters$` subject emits, `observable2` emits first? ‍♂️

I have tried using the `mergeMap` operator on `observable2`, to make it "depend" on `observable1` --> but to no help at all.

**Reproduce**

Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tma9pg) to a stackblitz with typescript and rxjs.

Comment: Based on what logic should `observable2` receive the event first? You can just switch the order of subscriptions.

Comment: I simply want to guarantee that `observable2` always emits after `observable1` - that's it.

Comment: use [concatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) in this case

Comment: Nice question, with a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the emissions from `observable1` asynchronous before passing them to `observable2`:

```
const observable2 = observable1.pipe(
  observeOn(asyncScheduler),
  map(() => 'observable2')
);
```

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xqcyqk?file=index.ts

Comment: wow - it actually works. What does `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` accomplish here?

Comment: I think that this solution will not work all the time ! From the documentation of [asyncScheduler](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/asyncScheduler)  : _Schedule task as if you used setTimeout(task, duration)_. So the observeOn will put the map (the task) into the call stack and waits its turn to be executed. This will remains asynchronous because if the call stack contains a lot of tasks to be executed the second observable may precede the first one

Comment: @bubbles It doesn't matter how many tasks are in the queue. As far as `observable1` remains synchronous then `observable2` with `observeOn` will always receive the event after  `observable1`.